# Can't Mock Stored procedure in JOOQ

Tags: java, unit-testing, mockito, jooq

I am trying to mock a stored procedure that I generated with JOOQ. I don't know how to replace the mock, and a nullptr exception is being thrown.

Here is the code

```
public class MyClass {
    public void findResults() {
        DSLContext create = DSL.using(ConnectionManager.getConnection(), SQLDialect.MYSQL);
        SpFindResultsByOrder findResultsByOrder = new SpFindResultsByOrder(); // Exception!
        findResultsByOrder.execute(create.configuration());

    }
}
```

Test

```
@PrepareForTest({DSL.class, ConnectionManager.class})
@PowerMockIgnore("javax.management.*")
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
public class JOOQTest {

    @Test
    public void shouldFindResultsByOrder() extends Exception {
        mockStatic(DSL.class);
        mockStatic(ConnectionManager.class);
        Connection cnxn = mock(Connection.class);
        DSLContext create = mock(DSLContext.class);
        SpFindResultsByOrder sp = mock(SpFindResultsByOrder.class);

        when(ConnectionManager.getConnection()).withAnyArguments().thenReturn(cnxn);
        when(DSL.using(cnxn,SQLDialect.MYSQL).thenReturn(create);
        whenNew(SpFindResultsByOrder.class).withAnyArguments().thenReturn(sp);

        MyClass mc = new MyClass();
        mc.findResults();

     }
}
```

---

Context

I get a nullptr exception when I try to mock my JOOQ stored procedure object. This is a generated object that inherits from `AbstractRoutine<java.lang.Void>`.
At `SpFindResultsByOrder findResultsByOrder = new SpFindResultsByOrder();`, my mock is not being replaced. Instead an actual SpFindResultsByOrder is made, and I get a nullptr exception.

My exception looks like this:

`Method threw 'java.lang.NullPointerException' exception. Cannot evaluate com.example.generated.routines.SpFindResultsByOrder.toString()`

The schema object inside my StoredProcedure throws:

`Method threw 'java.lang.NullPointerException' exception. Cannot evaluate com.example.generated.MyDatabase.toString()`